# slope and deflection of beam engineering

Tags: structural-engineering

Here's my ans , but the ans given is EIy = -4953 , but i gt EIy = -5078 , anything wrong with my answer ? for slope at A , i gt EI(dy/dx) = 0 instead of EI(dy/dx) =625[image: 1]

[image: solution]

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: There's no content here - what is the shape of the beam? What is the material? **What did you do to get those answers**? What are the units for your answer? There's no way to answer this.

Comment: use m will do , this is a question from my book

Comment: "Determine the maximum deflection and slope at A" - Is B fixed then? Is it fixed in the middle? There's no mark anywhere that shows mechanical reference or supports. Why does EIymax occur at x=5? Why did you use that as your answer when you were asked to find deflection at A, which you have marked as "at A, x=0"?

Comment: the two ends are pinned , it's not shown clearly in the diagram . for uniformly distributed load , the maximum deflection will occur at the center , right ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks - The two ends are pinned?? If A is pinned, then how does it have a deflection? "Determine the maximum deflection and slope **at A**".

Comment: @Chuck, I think the question is just terribly worded. It wants both the maximum deflection (anywhere on the beam) and the slope at A. It would be better frased as "Determine the maximum slope at A and the maximum deflection".

Comment: ok , let it be Determine the the maximum deflection" , in my working , it occurs at x = 5 , then i gt the ans = -5078 , i smy ans correct ? or the given ans is correct ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks, here's a life-tip for you: the given answer is *always* correct. That should always be your default assumption. Only after having exhausted every single possible error you could have done should you even entertain the possibility that the book is wrong.

Comment: ok, could you notice where's my mistake ?

Comment: I am voting to close this as off-topic per [our policy on check-my-work questions](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/335/368).

Answer (score 4):

You messed up your integration from $EI\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ to $EIy$. It should be

$$EIy = \dfrac{75x^3}{6} - \dfrac{15x^4}{24} + c_1x + c_2$$

but your denominator for the first term is $3$, not $6$. (In your calculations, however, you seem to have used 6).

Also, your solving for the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ is incorrect. What you have is:

$$\begin{gather}
y(x=0)=0 \therefore c_2 = 0 \\
y(x=L)= \dfrac{75L^3}{6} - \dfrac{15L^4}{24} + c_1L = 0 \\
\therefore c_1 = \dfrac{15L^3}{24} - \dfrac{75L^2}{6} \\
\therefore EIy = \dfrac{75x^3}{6} - \dfrac{15x^4}{24} + \left(\dfrac{15L^3}{24} - \dfrac{75L^2}{6}\right)x \\
EIy(5) = -1953
\end{gather}$$

You'll notice my answer is different from the given answer, just as I said in a comment that the given answer is (almost) always right. You'll notice something, though: there's a single digit difference between my answer and the given one: change the $1$ in my answer to a $4$ and you get the given answer. Given that 1 and 4 are neighboring keys on the number pad, this could be easily explained as a typo in the book, instead of a calculation error on the author's part.

Not satisfied that this is right, I created a computer model to check my work and it checks out.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm, did the work independently and got the same answer.

Comment: for x = 5 , dey/dx should be = minimum= 0 , right ? why am i getting EI(dy/dx) = 625 ? for location A  , the dy/dx should be max , right ? why am i getting EI(dy/dx) =0 ? for location b , where x = 10 , i gt EI(dy/dx) = 1250

Comment: @kelvinmacks: I have no idea. My solution gives $EI\frac{dy}{dx}(0) = -EI\frac{dy}{dx}(L) = -625$ and $EI\frac{dy}{dx}(5) = 0$. If you get anything different, you're doing it wrong. And then that'd be a simple algebra mistake, which I can't help you with.